# Deleting values from raster file using ArcGIS Raster Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, delete

I have a raster that denotes certain landcover types.

How do I delete all of the pixels except for the ones I want?

I tried going through the symbology tab and while that deletes it for display it doesn't change the raster file itself, so if I were to delete and reload the file it would revert back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the reclassify tool in Spatial analyst to change your values to NoData (or any other values). You can also use the raster calculator to apply some rules e.g. `Con((raster>=20) & (raster<=30), raster)` will set to NoData all values that are not between 20 or 30.

Comment: There's also the SetNull tool.

Comment: Thanks you guys!  I used the Reclassify tool and it worked PERFECTLY.  I should have thought about that.  and Luke thanks for the tip on the SetNull tool, I'll keep that in mind if I need it again :)