# Clip raster by raster in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, clip

How can I get two different raster layers in ArcMap, that have exact the same edge?

I tried clipping or extract by mask but the output looks exactly like the input.

I only want to have these values that have a cell in the other raster.

In other words: I have a red and a black raster. In the first image I want to get rid of the black cells of the underlying raster. In the second image I want to get rid of the red cells of the underlying raster.

[image]

[image]

Comment: this may help?: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221979/deleting-values-from-raster-file-using-arcgis-raster-calculator

Comment: thanks for the link, but this doesn't help :) I want to get rid of the raster cells of one raster, that kind of "overlap" the other raster. Like the cells you see at the edge in the screenshots above. both pictures describe two rasters that are on top of each other. in the first picture the red is on top of the black raster in the second picture the black is on top of the red raster. In the first picutre I want to delete the black cells and in the second picture I want to delete the 6 red cells.

Comment: Not sure number of rasters you are dealing with, but could you convert the rasters to vector, make edits manually and then reconvert to raster (which have same properties as original rasters, of course)?

Comment: Also, if the cells of interest have easily distinguishable pixel values versus the other pixels in rasters, maybe try reclassify cells values to NoData?

Comment: I am dealing with 4 rasters. I thought about converting each raster to vextor polygons, dissolve these, intersect all 4 vector-layers and this will give my a clip-feature. I could use that to clip all 4 raster-layers. I will try that. But I guess there must be a simpler solution or I am overlooking something. Your second option will not work, because the pixels of the rasters are not easily distinguishable.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about working with NoData values?
If they are not properly labelled already, you could assign the white cells to the raster mask. That can be achieved for example by using the `Copy Raster` tool to modify the NoData Value.

You could also use the `Raster Calculator` to create a Mask raster using operations like AND/OR (something like `"raster1 == 255" | "raster2 == 255"` assuming that white = 255 in your screenshots)

Once you have this sorted you should be able to perform an `Extract By Mask` using the new raster with NoData values as a mask.

## Edited solution after the additional information provided in the comment:

`SetNull((IsNull("raster1") | IsNull("raster2")) == 1, "raster1")`, then `SetNull((IsNull("raster1") | IsNull("raster2")) == 1, "raster2")` using the `Raster Calculator` tool should do the trick

Comment: Hi Alessio, thanks for your post! All the white space are already NoData values. In both raster layers.

Comment: I suggest then to run `Raster Calculator` with a function like this `SetNull((IsNull("raster1") | IsNull("raster2")) == 1, "raster1")`. This will generate a raster where pixels will have a value of 1 if any of the two input raster pixels is NoData. We can then use that intermediate raster with the `SetNull` function to assign a new comprehensive mask to raster1. You can then rerun this function changing the last "raster1" to "raster2" to perform the same operation on the second raster. This method requires the SpatialAnalyst license

Comment: This is the reference for the SetNull operation http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/setting-cell-values-to-nodata-with-setnull.htm

Comment: so I could ask in the raster calculator to turn the values of the black raster to NoData, where the red raster has already a NoData value. And the same thing vice versa. right?

Comment: this part `(IsNull("raster1") | IsNull("raster2"))` uses a OR logic operator. Basically checks if pixel value in raster1 is NoData OR pixel value in raster2 is NoData, and returns a 1 if that is the case. So it should be able to merge both masks in one go, merging black pixels of your first screenshot, white ones and red pixels of your second screenshot. You then apply that mask using the SetNull operator

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to export a raster you want to use the boundaries of to polygon and then clip the new raster using the polygon boundaries